# How can I further shorten this Python script which copies the contents of one file to another file?

Tags: python

I'm reading Zed Shaw's "Learn Python The Hard Way". I'm up to exercise 17 ( http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex17.html ) and hit the wall on extra credit #'s 2 & 3. Zed wants me to shorten the script by eliminating anything that isn't necessary (he claims he can get it to run with just one line in the script).

Here is the original script...

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv

print "Copying from %s to %s" % (from_file, to_file)

# we could do these two on one line too, how?
input = open(from_file)
indata = input.read()

print "The input file is %d bytes long" % len(indata)

print "Does the output file exist? %r" % exists(to_file)
print "Ready, hit RETURN to continue, CTRL-C to abort."
raw_input()

output = open(to_file, 'w')
output.write(indata)

print "Alright, all done."

output.close()
input.close()
```

Here's what I was able to shorten the script to and still get it to run properly (by properly I mean that the script successfully copies the intended text to the intended file)...

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv

input = open (from_file)
indata = input.read ()

output = open (to_file, 'w')
output.write (indata)
```

I got rid of the print commands and the two close commands (please excuse if I'm using "command" incorrectly...I'm painfully new to coding and haven't gotten the jargon down yet).

Anything else I try to further shorten the script produces errors. For example, I tried to combine the "input" and "indata" commands into one line like so...

```
input = open (from_file, 'r')
```

Then I changed any "indata" references in the script to "input"...

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv

input = open (from_file, 'r')

output = open (to_file, 'w')
output.write (input)
```

But I get the following TypeError...

```
new-host:python Eddie$ python ex17.py text.txt copied.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex17.py", line 10, in <module>
    output.write (input)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

How would you go about shortening the script further...or shortening it down to just one line, as Zed suggests he can do?

Comment: I think it would be much more helpful if you could just post the current copy of your code *without* the previous history and ask for help on the error and optimization.

Comment: The point of the exercise is to reduce it to one line? Since you are copying files, simply use [`copy`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy)

Comment: Thanks @arxanas...didn't know there was a homework tag.

Comment: Thanks for advice @Levom...will keep it in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from sys import argv
open(argv[2], 'w').write(open(argv[1]).read())
```

is about as short as you can get that. You could use a semicolon to join them into one line, but that's just replacing a end-of-line character with something else and not really useful.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and it worked just fine. I wish I could say I full understand it, but I don't. I get the general idea, but how you formatted the line of code leaves me all "huh?". Probably because I haven't gotten too far in the Python tutorial and haven't yet seen similar examples.

Comment: "... and not really useful". Correct, and DEFINITELY not Pythonic.

Comment: Whoa...looks like you edited your answer. That one works too...still the semi "huh?" though.

Comment: @Eddie The idea is that `open().read()` on the infile returns a string, which immediately gets passed into `open().write()` on the outfile. It's the same code you wrote, except replacing references to variables with the actual values that those variables would been assigned. For instance, it replaces `output = open();output.write()` with `open().write()`. PLEASE don't get clever with that, though! Code is for people to read. If a temporary variable makes your intention clearer, use one! There's no bonus for cramming everything together in one inscrutable ball of code.

Comment: @holdenweb I don't know that I've ever used ";" to combine lines. I still mentally see those occurrences as two separate lines with ugly formatting.

Answer (score 4):

You could just use the `shutil` library and just let the OS carry the burden of a copy (instead of reading/writing data in Python).

```
import shutil
shutil.copy('from_file', 'to_file_or_directory_name')
```

Answer (score 3):

The current error you get is due to this:

```
input = open (from_file, 'r')

output.write (input)
```

[write()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=write#file.write) wants a string as parameter, you are giving it a file object.

Also, since you are trying to eliminate redundant things/shorten your code, small item, the default mode for [opening](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open) files is `'r'`ead, to that doesn't have to be specified when opening files for reading.

Also consider using the `with` construct to open and manage your files. The advantage is that the files will be closed for you automatically when you are done, or an exception is encountered, so no explicit `close()` is required.  E.g.,

```
with open('data.txt') as input:
   ## all of your file ops here
```

The [**PEP08 -- Style Guide for Python**](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (a "must read" for Python programmers) suggests not space between a function and the opening `(`.

I'm not sure a goal of one-line always results in a better or more readable solution, so that should be kept in mind.

Comment: Thanks...the Style Guide will come in super handy. Will be reading.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what the author was looking for, but here is the solution I came up with after many trial and error runs. I myself am a beginner so please bear that in mind. 
Here is the script:

```
               from sys import argv; script, from_file, to_file = argv
               in_file = open(from_file).read(); out_file = open(to_file, 'w').write(in_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

I took the 'in one line' directive quite literally and omitted the import lines altogether.
I find it more friendly too:

```
open(raw_input("To file? "), "w").write(open(raw_input("From file? ")).read())
```

Still doesn't close the 'To file', but hey, one line!

--EDIT--
I just noticed, Python *does* close the "To file" when the script finishes.
So, yay, one line!

Answer (score 0):

What about the following? Thought this would do.

```
open(input(),'w').write(open(input()).read())
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with (also a beginner):

```
    from sys import argv

    script, from_file, to_file = argv

    open(to_file, 'w').write(from_file)
```

It works, but I'm unsure if I left any files open. I think I maybe still need the close() command.